# is there a way to trace grads through self.put_variable method in flax?

Tags: python, jax, flax

I would like to trace the grads through the self.put_variable. Is there anyway to make that possible? Or another way to update the param supplied to the module that is traced?

```
import jax 
from jax import numpy as jnp 
from jax import grad,random,jit,vmap 
import flax 
from flax import linen as nn 


class network(nn.Module):
    input_size : int 
    output_size : int 
    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self,x):
        W = self.param('W',nn.initializers.normal(),(self.input_size,self.output_size))
        b = self.param('b',nn.initializers.normal(),(self.output_size,))

      
        self.put_variable("params","b",(x@W+b).reshape(5,))  
    
        return jnp.sum(x+b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    key = random.PRNGKey(0)
    key_x,key_param,key = random.split(key,3)
    x = random.normal(key_x,(1,5))

    module = network(5,5)
    param = module.init(key_param,x)
    print(param)
    #x,param = module.apply(param,x,mutable=["params"])
    #print(param)
    print(grad(module.apply,has_aux=True)(param,x,mutable=["params"]))
```

my output grads are :

```
FrozenDict({
    params: {
        W: DeviceArray([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32),
        b: DeviceArray([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32),
    },
```

What shows that it doesnt trace the grads through the self.variable_put method, as grads to W are all zero, while b clearly relies upon W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @jakevdp noted the test above is incorrect as b is still tied to the previous b. 
https://github.com/google/flax/discussions/2215 said that self.put_variable is traced.

Testing if that is actually the case using the code below:

```
import jax 
from jax import numpy as jnp 
from jax import grad,random,jit,vmap 
import flax 
from flax import linen as nn 

class network(nn.Module):
    input_size : int 
    output_size : int 
    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self,x):
        W = self.param('W',nn.initializers.normal(),(self.input_size,self.output_size))
        b = self.param('b',nn.initializers.normal(),(self.output_size,))

        b = x@W+b #update the b variable else it is still tied to the previous one.
        self.put_variable("params","b",(b).reshape(5,))  
     
        return jnp.sum(x+b)

def test_update(param,x):
    _, param = module.apply(param,x,mutable=["params"])
    return jnp.sum(param["params"]["b"]+x),param 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    key = random.PRNGKey(0)
    key_x,key_param,key = random.split(key,3)
    x = random.normal(key_x,(1,5))

    module = network(5,5)
    param = module.init(key_param,x)
    print(param)

    print(grad(test_update,has_aux=True)(param,x))
```

output:

```
FrozenDict({
    params: {
        W: DeviceArray([[ 0.01678762,  0.00234134,  0.00906202,  0.00027337,
                       0.00599653],
                     [-0.00729604, -0.00417799,  0.00172333, -0.00566238,
                       0.0097266 ],
                     [ 0.00378883, -0.00901531,  0.01898266, -0.01733185,
                      -0.00616944],
                     [-0.00806503,  0.00409351,  0.0179838 , -0.00238476,
                       0.00252594],
                     [ 0.00398197,  0.00030245, -0.00640218, -0.00145424,
                       0.00956188]], dtype=float32),
        b: DeviceArray([-0.00905032, -0.00574646,  0.01621638, -0.01165553,
                     -0.0285466 ], dtype=float32),
    },
})
(FrozenDict({
    params: {
        W: DeviceArray([[-1.1489547 , -1.1489547 , -1.1489547 , -1.1489547 ,
                      -1.1489547 ],
                     [-2.0069852 , -2.0069852 , -2.0069852 , -2.0069852 ,
                      -2.0069852 ],
                     [ 0.98777294,  0.98777294,  0.98777294,  0.98777294,
                       0.98777294],
                     [ 0.9311977 ,  0.9311977 ,  0.9311977 ,  0.9311977 ,
                       0.9311977 ],
                     [-0.2883922 , -0.2883922 , -0.2883922 , -0.2883922 ,
                      -0.2883922 ]], dtype=float32),
        b: DeviceArray([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32),
    },
}), FrozenDict({
    params: {
        W: DeviceArray([[ 0.01678762,  0.00234134,  0.00906202,  0.00027337,
                       0.00599653],
                     [-0.00729604, -0.00417799,  0.00172333, -0.00566238,
                       0.0097266 ],
                     [ 0.00378883, -0.00901531,  0.01898266, -0.01733185,
                      -0.00616944],
                     [-0.00806503,  0.00409351,  0.0179838 , -0.00238476,
                       0.00252594],
                     [ 0.00398197,  0.00030245, -0.00640218, -0.00145424,
                       0.00956188]], dtype=float32),
        b: DeviceArray([-0.01861148, -0.00523183,  0.03968921, -0.01952654,
                     -0.06145691], dtype=float32),
    },
}))
```

The first FrozenDict is the original parameters. 
The second FrozenDict is the grads, clearly being traced through self.put_variable. 
The last FrozenDict is the parameters, where we can see that b is correctly updated.

Comment: I wouldn't write this as an answer. Instead of it edit your question and mark this with update / fix...

Answer (score 0):

The output of your model is `jnp.sum(x + b)`, which has no dependence on `W`, which in turn implies that the gradient with respect to `W` should be zero. With this in mind, the output you show above looks to be correct.

Edit: It sounds like you're expecting the result of `x@W+b` that you used in your variable to be reflected in the value of `b` used in the return statement; perhaps you want something like this?

```py
    def __call__(self,x):
        W = self.param('W',nn.initializers.normal(),(self.input_size,self.output_size))
        b = self.param('b',nn.initializers.normal(),(self.output_size,))

        b = x@W+b
        self.put_variable("params","b",b.reshape(5,)) 
    
        return jnp.sum(x+b)
```

That said, it's unclear to me from the question what your ultimate goal is, and given that you're asking about such an uncommon construct, I suspect this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you can edit your question to say more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: self.put_variable("params","b",(x@W+b).reshape(5,)) updates b and relies upon W and b, so jnp.sum(x + b) relies upon W, x and b. As b is now b(x,W,b_0)

Comment: if the parameters are in a pytree I can do the same thing but it tracks the grads, but I don't want to do it in plain jax as I want to use the clean parameter management of flax.

Comment: I see what you mean b is still bound to the previous b value, instead of the new one.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to make self modifying networks. I'm currently trying to recreate the results from "A Modern Self-Referential Weight Matrix That Learns to Modify Itself". But for that I need to be able to do new_param,y = f(param,x) what I struggled with as I'm quite new to flax. Where the new_param are depended upon the old param and x so I can trace grads back to the old param

Comment: I solved the problem in the end (above answer), thanks for your help either way. :)